# Can we use mailchimp for user notification emails in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp

Can we use [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) for system in rails 3.0 emails like password reset email, account confirmation email and other emails like when user receives a message from another user and all other system

Answer (score 6):

The type of email you're referring to, is called "Transactional Email" and MailChimp is for "Bulk Email". So no, you can't use MailChimp for that. It's actually against their ToS.

However, the fine people over in Atlanta launched [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) just last year. Mandrill handles transactional email like Diego Maradona handles a soccer ball.

Mandrill offers a great number of API methods with awesome [documentation](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/).

Comment: Thanks for defining the term 'transactional email', that's super helpful for someone just googling for results! I love it when I can cut straight to the heart of the jargon.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use of Sengrid - http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html.
I am not familiar with MailChimp, but I suppose that to send messge thourgh MailChimp you must  add a contact to campaign, follow-up or something which is much overhead in my opinion.